# How to create a pandas column that counts instances of a value, based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame of extracted forum posts where the opening post for each thread is represented by the number 1 in the thread_opening column. The post_number column counts how many comments there are for each unique string in the thread_name column (i.e. for each thread). It looks something like this:

| user_name | thread_name | post_text | post_number | thread_opening |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BoxCutter | It's Okay When We Do It. | ..... | 1 | 1 |
| Docket_33 | It's Okay When We Do It. | ..... | 2 | 0 |
| Hearmeout | It's Okay When We Do It. | ..... | 3 | 0 |
| yez | Science | ..... | 1 | 1 |
| Mainländer | Science | ..... | 2 | 0 |
| 400z | Science | ..... | 3 | 0 |
| Farnham | Science | ..... | 4 | 0 |

I'm trying to create a new column, let's call it 'thread_comments_count' that counts the number of posts in each thread. Essentially, for every row where thread_opening = 1, I wish to count the post_number. While, where thread_opening = 0, the thread_comments_count value will = 0.

Comment: How looks expected ouput from sample data?

Answer (score 2):

If `thread_opening` already exists, you can use [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html):

```
df['post_number'] = df.groupby(df['thread_opening'].cumsum()).cumcount()
```

If you want the total, only when `thread_opening` is 1:

```
df['thread_comments_count'] = (df.groupby('thread_name')['thread_name']
                                 .transform('size')
                                 .where(df['thread_opening'].eq(1), 0)
                              )
```

Output:

```
    user_name               thread_name post_text  post_number  thread_opening  thread_comments_count
0   BoxCutter  It's Okay When We Do It.     .....            1               1                      3
1   Docket_33  It's Okay When We Do It.     .....            2               0                      0
2   Hearmeout  It's Okay When We Do It.     .....            3               0                      0
3         yez                   Science     .....            1               1                      4
4  Mainländer                   Science     .....            2               0                      0
5        400z                   Science     .....            3               0                      0
6     Farnham                   Science     .....            4               0                      0
```

Comment: this has worked a charm! Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['thread_comments_count'] = np.where(df['thread_opening'].eq(1),
                                    df['thread_name'].map(df['thread_name'].value_counts()),
                                    0)
print (df)

     user_name                thread_name post_text  post_number  \
0   BoxCutter   It's Okay When We Do It.     .....             1   
1   Docket_33   It's Okay When We Do It.     .....             2   
2   Hearmeout   It's Okay When We Do It.     .....             3   
3         yez                    Science     .....             1   
4  Mainländer                    Science     .....             2   
5        400z                    Science     .....             3   
6     Farnham                    Science     .....             4   

   thread_opening  thread_comments_count  
0               1                      3  
1               0                      0  
2               0                      0  
3               1                      4  
4               0                      0  
5               0                      0  
6               0                      0
```